# Qual é a origem da expressão "Zé Arruela" ou "Zé Ruela"?

Tags: origem-histórica

Eu até sei o que significa. Tem vários significados possíveis em vários contextos, embora a linha geral seja a mesma.

> Pessoa sem ação, incapaz de sair de qualquer situação que apresente alguma dificuldade; o mesmo que bunda mole.

[Dicionário informal](http://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/z%C3%A9%20ruela/).

> Indivíduo que não tem alta capacidade mental para discernir fatos.

[Wiki Gírias](http://pt.girias.wikia.com/wiki/Z%C3%A9_Ruela).

> Zé Ruela é uma gíria para adjetivar uma pessoa passiva, que não consegue pensar numa solução para resolver uma situação difícil. Pode ser também uma pessoa desprovida de sabedoria, que é lenta de raciocínio.
>
> O termo Zé Ruela é usado em várias classes sociais, para diversos tipos de pessoa, sejam elas membros de uma grande empresa, um vizinho, ou o garçom de um bar. Geralmente o Zé Ruela é um indivíduo sem atitude, com baixa capacidade de resolução de problemas, avesso ao envolvimento com tarefas que exijam responsabilidade.
>
> Zé Ruela é aquela pessoa descompromissada ao extremo, está sempre descontente com tudo e não possui uma postura proativa, preferindo deixar como está para ver como é que fica, pode-se dizer também que é um sujeito acomodado.
>
> Nas empresas, o Zé Ruela é responsável por muitos dos problemas dos gestores, pois geralmente ele contamina o ambiente em que se encontra, não contribui para o desenvolvimento da empresa nem para relacionamentos interpessoais saudáveis.

[Significados](http://www.significados.com.br/ze-ruela/).

Mas qual a origem deste termo?

Comment: Uma possibilidade é vir de *arruela*, o anel chato metálico que fica entalado entre a porca e material onde o parafuso está enroscado (*anilha* em Portugal): o Zé Arruela seria tão atado e enrascado como uma arruela debaixo da porca.

Comment: Aém do apropriado comentário do @Jacinto tem ai a conotação sexual já que *arruela/ruela* também são gírias para ânus. O Zé Ruela seria aquele cara que *só se ferra*

Comment: Pode ser zé da ruela (rua pequena).

Comment: Nunca ouvi esta expressao

Comment: @jean, na verdade acho essa tua sugestão mais plausível que a minha. Estou a ver o pessoal usar uma gíria para *ânus* com esse significado de ’atado, incapaz’, etc. Em Portugal, com um significado diferente, mas com alguma relação (partilha o sentido de ’pessoa de pouco valor’) tens [*enc##ado*](https://dicionario.priberam.org/enconado) e [*c##inhas*](https://dicionario.priberam.org/coninhas).

Answer (score 1):

O certo é arruela, esta peça existe para firmar o parafuso e aumentar a sua vida útil. Uma coisa simples, mas ignorada por uma boa parte de mecânicos; eles acham que a arruela não serve para nada, assim como alguns Zés por aí, mesmo os não nascidos Josés. 
Essa gíria como todas outras tem sua origem meio que desconhecida, haja vista que até onde se sabe ninguém tem ideia exatamente onde e quando surgiu. Entretanto, como uma boa paulista e pelas características da palavra, acredito que tenha surgido em São Paulo.

Referências:

- https://www.significados.com.br/ze-ruela/
- https://www.qualeagiria.com.br/giria/ze-ruela/
- https://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/z%C3%A9%20ruela/

Comment: Oi @ADRIANA, poderias buscar alguma referência sobre as expressões. Normalmente, buscamos isso para termos uma base no que estamos citando. Obrigado pela contribuição!

Comment: Já mencionei estas referencias.

Answer (score 0):

Zé Ruela era dono de uma lojinha de auto peças de desmanche, dentre elas muitas arruelas, claro, em Paracatu, MG, nos 50 e 60.
Como as peças que revendia eram muito desgastadas, raramente serviam para serem reutilizadas e os carros davam pane novamente.
Daí a origem do termo, que vem do nome de um cara que vendia produtos sem nenhuma valia a mais.
José, que vendia arruelas sem valor nem confiança.

Comment: Silvano, bem-vindo aqui ao site. Essa explicação é muito interessante, mas precisa de ser apoiada com referências credíveis. Existe uma imensidão de histórias inventadas sobre origem de expressões, e temos de ter alguma maneira de separar o trigo do joio.

Answer (score 0):

Esse termo pejorativo faz referência ao nome José, um nome comum, bíblico, que muitas vezes é usado como ofensa para se referir a uma pessoa comum: "Um Zé na vida". Uso incorreto da palavra que não leva em consideração sua origem e importância antropológica.

Já o termo Ruela é uma versão popular de arruela, um disco que se coloca entre o parafuso e a superfície de aperto, o que permite aumentar a "cabeça" do parafuso, entre outras utilidades, compra-se muitas arruelas em sacos a baixíssimo valor. Usado pejorativamente como referência a uma peça barata, comum, de menor importância.

A junção Zé Ruela forma uma ofensa grave: comum, barato e de menor importância. Utilizado em meios onde as pessoas têm menores instrução acadêmica e trato social.

Comment: É utilizada em todo o Brasil ?

Answer (score -1):

Indivíduo que não tem alta capacidade mental para discernir fatos. Wiki Gírias. Zé Ruela é uma gíria para adjetivar uma pessoa passiva, que não consegue pensar numa solução para resolver uma situação difícil. Pode ser também uma pessoa desprovida de sabedoria, que é lenta de raciocínio